# Militaristic vs militant

Tags: word-choice

I have a friend with whom every conversation turns into a power struggle. His tone of voice is very sharp and snappy. Should I describe this person's personality as militaristic or militant?

**Militaristic** - advocating or pursuing an aggressive military policy; hawkish.
"the president and his militaristic administration"

**Militant** - combative and aggressive in support of a political or social cause, and typically favoring extreme, violent, or confrontational methods.
"a militant nationalist"

Comment: _militant_ is a better choice unless your friend is discussing military matters. I would suggest _[combative](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confrontational)_ "Tending to deal with situations in an aggressive way; hostile or argumentative."

Comment: I like the suggestion of 'combative'. To me 'militant' connotes (perhaps fanatical) attachment to a particular cause. 'Bellicose' is another word that might be suitable to your purpose.